# Understanding Firewall

Tags: networking, firewall

So I am trying to understand Firewall concepts.
I know what a Firewall is. My question is to try and understand whether, I need to setup firewall on my linux machine. If there is a firewall setup on the router?
What I am having trouble in understanding is, I had a perfectly working system(So maybe not perfectly, Okayish) But it was communicating over https.
Then we applied firewall OUTBbound rules on the router only allowing below ports.

```
Allow TCP xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/32 443 to Destination any any
Allow UDP xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/32 53  to Destination any any
Allow ICMP xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/32    to Destination any any
Allow UDP xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/32 143 to Destination any any
Allow TCP xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/32 143 to Destination any any
Allow UDP xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/32 123 to Destination any any
Deny on all other
```

After these rules are applied my system stopped communicating.
Now before I start setting firewall using iptables. Shouldn't this just work without me setting anything on my machine?

Do I have to set firewall rules on my end. If so why ?

Comment: Why has this been closed?  Anyway I have found the answer. Thanks a lot @yoonix and the other guy

Answer (score 1):

> `Allow TCP xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/32 443 to Destination any any`

That ACL entry permits connections *from* the specified IP, TCP port 443 to any destination. It should work if you apply it to the server-facing port on ingress or to the WAN-facing port on egress, so the server is permitted to reply.

However, since rogue packets can already endanger your server when received you should apply the inverse firewall rule *on ingress to the WAN-facing port*. That ensures that no malicious packet ever reaches the server, e.g.:

`Allow TCP any any to Destination xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/32 443`

Generally, ACLs should be applied as early as possible, when a packet tries to enter your infrastructure.

Comment: I have no networking experience at all. I am trying to understand what you have said. So please correct me if I am wrong. Does it mean that, since they have applied this rule. So I have to apply the inverse on my system? or Tell them to allow any TCP communication on 443

Comment: It depends on which interface you apply the rule to and in which direction.

Comment: I think it is on WWAN outbound rules.